# Receiving a lack of semi-colon error

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I have place all the semicolons on the below paragraph(ongesturestart) yet it claims that i did not place a semicolon.Is it because of wrong scripting style or lacking of something?

```
 outerDiv.ongesturestart = function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      gestureScale = event.scale;
      parent.document.ontouchmove = function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
      };
  }

 outerDiv.ongestureend = function (event) {
 ====^
 lint warning: missing semicolon

      event.preventDefault();

      if (event.scale > gestureScale) {
          ZoomIn();
      }
     else {
          ZoomOut();
      }
      parent.document.ontouchmove = null;
  };
```

Comment: You are missing it at the function closing `}` before that.

Comment: u mean at the first paragraph }: is it?

Comment: Yes, did you do that?

Comment: ohh u mean at the end of ongesturestart paragraph i didn't add the semicolon causing the error?

Comment: put the semicolon `;` on the last `}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semicolon here:

```
 outerDiv.ongesturestart = function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   gestureScale = event.scale;
   parent.document.ontouchmove = function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
   };
};
```

At the last `}` of `outerDiv.ongesturestart`